# how to remove duplicates when using pandas concat to combine two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have two data from.

df1 with columns: id,x1,x2,x3,x4,....xn

df2 with columns: id,y.

`df3 =pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)`

when I use pandas concat to combine them, it became

`id,y,id,x1,x2,x3...xn`.

there are two id here.How can I get rid of one.

I have tried :

`df3=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)`.

but not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataFrames are concatenated on the index. Make sure that `id` is the index before concatenating:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1.set_index('id'), 
                 df2.set_index('id')], axis=1).reset_index()
```

Or, better yet, use `join`:

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, on='id')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The first one works. The second shows "You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat"

Comment: Apparently your `id` columns in the two dataframes are of different data types: one is strings, the other is numbers. They may look the same, but they are not. Convert them to the same datatype with `.astype()`.

Answer (score 0):

`drop_duplicates()` only removes rows that are completely identical.

what you're looking for is `pd.merge()`.

`pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id)`